# A.Compile cpp2html.c to produce cpp2html.o

Tags: unix, gcc, makefile

```
Your makefile does too much work when only cpp2html.c has been changed:
gcc -g -c cpp2html.c
gcc -g cpp2html.o lex.yy.o
gcc -g -DDEBUG cpp2html.o lex.yy.o -o cpp2html
```

does not work, I have tried almost every sequence. My code follows:

```
cpp2html: cpp2html.o lex.yy.o
        gcc {g cpp2html.o lex.yy.o
        gcc -g -DDEBUG cpp2html.o lex.yy.o -o cpp2html
cpp2html.o: cpp2html.c
        gcc -g  -c cpp2html.c
lex.yy.c: cppscanner.l
        flex cppscanner.l
lex.yy.o: lex.yy.c
        gcc -g -c lex.yy.c
```

Comment: What is `gcc -g cpp2html.o lex.yy.o` supposed to be doing anyway?

Comment: Taking the first gcc out worked. Thanks a lot @WillBriggs

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34056157/a-compile-cpp2html-c-to-produce-cpp2html-o/45051452#comment55869289_34056157), taking the first `gcc` out solves the problem.